# Google maps api return text directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have implemented google maps api to show multiple routes between locations.  I also get text directions displayed for each route.

```
 // Create a unique DirectionsRenderer 'i'
            renderArray[i] = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            renderArray[i].setMap(map);
            renderArray[i].setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
```

setPanel only renders the directions on the map i'd like access to the directions so i can send them via ajax to another function.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for the call `directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {`, Google Maps returns you a JSON object, and when you dig into it, you would realized they store the steps from the top result in `response.routes[0].legs[0].steps`

That being said, all you have to do is to take information out from the JSON object. Here is an example on how to do it. http://jsfiddle.net/cen5Ls77/1/

Hope it helps.